# Different Global Git Init template config based on multiple github instances

Tags: git, github

I am trying to enable couple of git hooks globally for all my commits at work. I achieved this by setting

```
git config --global init.templatedir '~/.git_template'
```

I want to enable this in order to make sure all my commit msg at work has a corresponding bug id. This works exactly as I expected.

Now my problem is when I want to commit something to my personal github account, these hooks are triggered which I do not want.

How can I restrict these global templates to a particular github instance only ? I was able to seperate the SSH keys by configuring `$HOME/.ssh/config` file. Is something similar possible here also ?

Few restrictions I have:

- Server side hooks are not allowed at work instance
- If I have to set `$REPO/.git/hooks` folder manually, it defeats the purpose as I have to always remind myself to set them

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to set the config locally to your repo then? So instead of doing a --global, you do a --local and so the config option varies between the two repos (assuming you have two different repos, one for work stuff and another for your personal/home stuff).

From https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config:
"...When writing, the new value is written to the repository local configuration file by default, and options --system, --global, --file  can be used to tell the command to write to that location (you can say --local but that is the default)."

--global

For writing options: write to global ~/.gitconfig file rather than the repository .git/config, write to $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config file if this file exists and the ~/.gitconfig file doesn’t.

For reading options: read only from global ~/.gitconfig and from $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config rather than from all available files.

--local

For writing options: write to the repository .git/config file. This is the default behavior.

For reading options: read only from the repository .git/config rather than from all available files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but setting it locally is what I am trying to avoid. My only use case is that if I missed to set this locally for a repo. Usually I work on couple of repos in parallel at work due to the nature of components. What I am looking for is a way to make sure the same hooks executes no matter what when I have to do 1 time setup only. Is that possible ?

Comment: Perhaps you can parse the last command stored in your .bash.history file to examine it for the repo to which you are pushing. I think you need to change the history such that it writes it out for each command instead of caching it.

Comment: Interesting idea. Let me try this also. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I ended up adding some logic in my hook's code. If the commit message has a certain keyword, then it will by pass the bug id logic. Not the optimum way, but a quick work around.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to try to tackle this come to mind:

First, you could use separate git aliases like `clone-personal`, or `init-work` which pass along a different `--template` argument to the `clone` or `init` subcommands for each environment. Then of course you'd have to remember to use those aliases instead of a plain `init` or `clone` which isn't ideal.

For cloning, you could take the above one step further by matching the passed-in URL against a certain pattern to decide whether it is a work vs. personal address and then automatically passing in the correct `--template` option. That would let you use one script/alias for cloning.

If you have the alias execute a shell command (or just use a separate shell script instead of a git alias), it could also look at anything in your environment (for example, $PWD to determine if you are in a "work" subdirectory or a "personal" subdirectory) and then pass a different `--template` option to git. Then you could just use one alias/script/bash function (for each subcommand).

If there are other configuration items (in addition to hooks) that you might want to be different between your work vs. personal repos, you could instead use a simpler option to just not define a user.email configuration field globally. In this case, git will disallow you to commit the first time you try and you'll need to define your user.email configuration field. You can then use a custom alias/script/bash function that you manually run within the repository to configure it for a 'work' or 'personal' environment. For example, a `git-config-work` bash function could copy in your hooks and locally configure `user.email` for your work-repository commits.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. These are interesting approaches. Let me try this.

Comment: I ended up adding some logic in my hook's code. If the commit message has a certain keyword, then it will by pass the bug id logic. Not the optimum way, but a quick work around.

Comment: If you keep your projects under different directories, your hook could also check the repository location or working directory to decide whether or not to apply the logic. Just another option...